# TCPresenceEvent triggered when device goes to background?

Tags: ios, twilio

I am using the Twilio presence delegate method `func device(device: TCDevice!, didReceivePresenceUpdate presenceEvent: TCPresenceEvent!) {`. I have two questions about this method:

1. It seems like this method is called with a `not available` event for a device that goes to the background, even though you can still call the device (since it's running in a background mode). Is this intended behavior?
2. How does this method scale when the number of connected devices increases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

I checked and switching to `Not Available` when an app goes into background is indeed the current behavior, though I agree its not the best one.  I've opened an issue with our engineering team to see if it can be changed.

Not sure I totally understand what your asking with the second point.  Can you provide a bit more info?

Hope that helps.